# Installing IIS8 with command line parameters

Tags: c#, windows, iis, windows-8, iis-8

By calling pkgmgr.exe from C# with the following parameters, 
I was able to enable IIS 7 features ASP.NET and .NET Extensibility under Application Development Section.

`/iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;...... /norestart /quiet`

For IIS8, it is not working any more because there is no ASP.NET option under Application Development Features.
Instead there are ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.5 (.NET Extensibility 3.5 and  .NET Extensibility 4.5).

How can I enable them using pkgmgr.exe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I saw your question yesterday and looked it up on a regular basis in hope of someone answering it. Sadly, no one did, the good news though I've found a solution so I'm sharing it to you.

The IIS-ASPNET is still there and it enables ASP.NET 3.5. You still need `IIS-NetFxExtensibility`. The difference lies in that those two now have an additional prerequisite, `NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45`.

So if you want to enable ASP.NET 3.5 you need : `IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45`

For ASP.NET 4.5 you need : `IIS-ASPNET45;IIS-NetFxExtensibility45;NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45`